# Can one ComboBox selection be bound to two different data?

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox, multibinding

I'm not sure if this is possible or not. I have created a ComboBox like this...

```
<ComboBox Name="testType"
          Margin="0,5,0,0"
          IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
          DisplayMemberPath="Description"
          SelectedValue="{Binding MyClass.Id, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectedValuePath="Id"/>
```

with code behind that loads up the available options...

```
        DataTable testCatList = TestTypeBase.GetAll();
        testType.ItemsSource = testCatList.DefaultView;
```

so that it properly displays all the items in MyClass. When the user makes a selection, the Id field in MyClass gets updated as intended. Great.

Here's my problem: My testCatList contains both the Id and the Description for each of the rows, and I'd like both of those fields to be bound to the current MyClass instance. So here's what I tried:

```
<ComboBox Name="testType"
          Margin="0,5,0,0"
          IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
          DisplayMemberPath="Description">
    <ComboBox.SelectedValue>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{???}">
            <Binding Path="MyClass.Id" Mode="TwoWay"/>
            <Binding Path="MyClass.Description" Mode="TwoWay"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </ComboBox.SelectedValue>
</ComboBox>
```

Here, I'd like to have MyClass.Id set to the selected Id and the MyClass.Description set to the selected Description. As you can see, I have removed the SelectedValuePath because I don't just want the Id any more. But I don't know what to use for the Converter (see the question marks above).

Any ideas, oh experts of StackOverflow? Thanks.

Comment: I would start with a one way converter just to get it going.  Did you create a converter in the code behind?  If so please post what you have.

Comment: No,I have not created a converter for this because the data is already in the correct format:  DataTable.Id > MyClass.Id and DataTable.Description > MyClass.Description. I thought there would be a way to bind the two fields without using code.

Comment: There is no way to do combine or split without a converter that I know of.  Does the Converter syntax not give you a indication it is expecting a converter?  If it was a class you might be able to create a Property that is the combination so it looks like a single value.

Comment: Okay now I'm confused. I'm not combining or splitting the data, am I? Well I guess I have a class that I am trying to "split up" into its properties. Is that the right way to look at this? And if so, do you have an example of how this converter might look?

Comment: I'll try to word this a little differently, in case we're talking about two different things... MyClass has an Id property and a Description property (among others). The ComboBox's SelectedItem has an Id field and a Description field. I am trying to make it that when the user picks an item, MyClass gets updated with the selected item's Id and Description.

Comment: What about the answer from Dummy01 does give you what you want - a reference to the Selected MyClass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly try using `SelectedItem`property instead of `SelectedValue`.
In that way you will get the selected `MyClass` instance and of course all of its properties.

```
SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentSelectedMyClassItem}"
```

Comment: Yes, that makes sense that I would need the whole selected item, not just a value from within it--thanks! But I'm still stuck at the Converter value to use in my MultiBinding to populate just 2 (of many) fields in MyClass.